# Add radio buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am having some serious issue with jquery mobile am build a learning reponse system.Now i want to dynamically populate the question page each time there is a question to be answered. so far i have been able to do all that but currently my radio button are refusing to follow the normal jquery order when i call them dynamically. When i call the dynamically the design disrupts but when i hard code it i get exactly what am expecting. the image below is an example of wat am trying to explain. the upper distorted radio buttons are the dynamic ones the lower 2 are the hard coded ones.

this is the code i used:

```
var possibleAnswers=poss_ans.split(",");//poss_ans is string containing all the answer from the database


        for (var i =0; i < possibleAnswers.length; i++) {

                var label = sp[i];
                   $radio = $('<input />', { type: "radio" }); 
                   var $label = $('<label />', { text: label});
                   var wrapper = $('<div />');
                   wrapper.append($label).append($radio);;

                    $('div#poss_ans').append(wrapper);                      
            }
```

Please this is my html  am sorry but am not realy good with the fiddle thats why i didnt post there.

```
    <fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
            <h1 id="title">H1 Heading</h1>
            <p id="question">The question</p>


            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset  data-role="controlgroup">
                <div id="poss_ans"></div>


                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
                    <label for="radio-choice-2">6</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
                    <label for="radio-choice-3">4</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
                    <label for="radio-choice-3">8</label><input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
                    <label for="radio-choice-3">2</label>


            </fieldset>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Any help or contribution at all would grateful.Thanks
[image: dynamic and hard coded]

Comment: perhaps the `;;` is part of the issue?

Comment: can you please post your code in a js fiddle?

Comment: Please post some HTML. This is definitely a problem with missing styles or wrong CSS classes.

Comment: @mystro `id` values are meant to be unique, you can't use the same one over and over again. Can you also post the CSS? I've run this HTML with no problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery Mobile, after adding controls dynamically you need to initialize the widgets or call refresh on them so they apply the jQM classes.  For your case, you can simplify the HTML:

```
<h1 id="title">H1 Heading</h1>
<p id="question">The question</p>
<fieldset  data-role="controlgroup">
    <div id="poss_ans" ></div>
</fieldset>
```

Then in the script. you need to add a name to the radio buttons so that checking one unchecks the others. Also add an id and in the label a for that points at the associated id. Finally, after all appending is done, call enhanceWithin() on the div to initialize the checkboxradio widgets and then tell the controlgroup fieldset to refresh itself.

```
var $posans = $('#poss_ans');    
for (var i = 0; i < possibleAnswers.length; i++) {
    var label = possibleAnswers[i];
    $radio = $('<input />', {
        id: 'rad' + i,
        name: 'possibleAnswers',
        type: "radio",
        value: possibleAnswers[i],
    });
    var $label = $('<label />', {
        for: 'rad' + i,
        text: label
    });

    $posans.append($label).append($radio);
}     
$posans.enhanceWithin().closest("fieldset").controlgroup("refresh");
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tw0k5qkc/5/)**

Answer (score 3):

After testing your code and putting in the default string of values and also adding in the value to the dynamically created radio I can confirm it's working fine. I would imagine your issue is that there is problem with the main part of your HTML. But as you haven't added it, i can't confirm it.

Here's your javascript code:

```
var poss_ans = "6,4,8,2";
var possibleAnswers = poss_ans.split(","); //poss_ans is string containing all the answer from the database

for (var i = 0; i < possibleAnswers.length; i++) {

    var label = possibleAnswers[i];
    $radio = $('<input />', {
        type: "radio",
        value: possibleAnswers[i],
    });
    var $label = $('<label />', {
        text: label
    });
    var wrapper = $('<div />');
    wrapper.append($label).append($radio);

    $('div#poss_ans').append(wrapper);
}
```

And the HTML is used:

```
<div id="poss_ans"></div>
```

And finally, a working Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/tw0k5qkc/

Comment: Thanks for the help. i got the same output u getting now but  i just dont understand why it cant pick the attributes automatically like the hard coded ones. i have tried everything i know am adding my html so take a look at that too. thank you very much

Comment: I've seen your problem. There are TONNES of classes being added dynamically to those radio buttons/labels. That's why they don't look the same

Comment: Don't use something that appends so many classes :P Write the styling from scratch

Comment: ok i havent tried that yet so i would try that but what if jquery overrides my styles.

Comment: Thanks so much @andy it worked well check the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/mystro/L7Lr2vyy/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/mystro/L7Lr2vyy/3/). I think am am beginning to like the fiddle .